# Is there a site where one can poll Ubuntu users?

Tags: users

Is there a place to poll Ubuntu users other than www.ubuntuforums.org?

Suppose for instance one wants to ask subjective questions like: *Which media player do you use?* or *Are you satisfied with Ubuntu on the latest Dell notebook?* etc. etc.

Comment: You didn't precise language (English only?). There are forums in a lot of languages, for example [Ubuntu-fr](http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/) for French.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to want to hold long-term discussions (that couldn't be quickly satisfied in our chat or IRC), Ubuntu Forums is the right place for it.

The system here isn't designed for polling/subjective questions while UbuntuForums has a built in module for asking a poll question and allowing discussion beneath it.